# Ruby If .. Else .. End / Increment: Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a class method that iterates through an array of Order objects. I'm using data from there to build a hash. One of my if blocks inside the iterable is:

```
if !(report_hash[user_id][reason])
    report_hash[user_id][reason] = 1
else
    report_hash[user_id][reason]++
end
```

When I run this method I get:

```
 .rb:66 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Line 66 is where the `end` lives. Why is Ruby not expecting there to be an end statement at the end of this block? I am planning to move all the conditional logic into separate class methods once everything works but I have been trying to figure this out and am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **increment method `++` is not legal in Ruby**, use `+= 1` instead:

```
if !(report_hash[user_id][reason])
    report_hash[user_id][reason] = 1
else
    report_hash[user_id][reason] += 1
end
```

---

**A little improvement** (code size): I would refactor this code to the following:

```
report_hash[user_id][reason] ||= 1 # this will set report_hash[user_id][reason] to 1 if it is nil
report_hash[user_id][reason] += 1
```

Comment: Hmmm I could have sworn I looked up incrementing for Ruby and found this operator. I want to increment whatever is the value attached to the reason key for each user id so I imagine something like `report_hash[user_id][reason] += report_hash[user_id][reason]`

Comment: Hmm I don't understand your comment @ChrisClouten ... Can you try with other words? Maybe with an example?

Comment: So if report_hash[user_id][reason] is not nil, I want to increment whatever the current value is by one. Which I realize your example does, I think I just had a total brain fart on the += 1.

Comment: ahah that's because its friday ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't have `++` operator. Instead, you should have:

```
report_hash[user_id][reason] += 1
```